# C# Retrieve Common Records by LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have a database with the table that keeps `user_id`s and `tag_id`s. I want to write a function which takes two `user_id`s and returns the `tag_id`s that both users have in common.

These are the sample rows from the database:

```
   User_id     Tag_id
     1          100
     1          101
     2          100
     3          100
     3          101
     3          102
```

What I want from my function is that when I call my function like `getCommonTagIDs(1, 3)`, it should return `(100,101)`. What I did so far is that I keep the rows which are related to `user_id` in two different lists and then using for loops, return the common `tag_id`s.

```
 using (TwitterDataContext database = TwitterDataContext.CreateTwitterDataContextWithNoLock())
        {

            IEnumerable<Usr_Tag> tags_1 = database.Usr_Tags.Where(u => u.User_id == userID1).ToList();
            IEnumerable<Usr_Tag> tags_2 = database.Usr_Tags.Where(u => u.User_id == userID2).ToList();

            foreach (var x in tags_1)
            {
                foreach (var y in tags_2) {
                    if (x.Tag_id == y.Tag_id) {
                        var a =database.Hashtags.Where(u => u.Tag_id==x.Tag_id).SingleOrDefault();
                        Console.WriteLine(a.Tag_val);  
                    }

                }
            }
        }
```

What I want to ask is that, instead of getting all rows from database and searching for the common `tag_id`s in the function, I want to get the common `tag_id`s  directly from database with LINQ by making the calculations on the database side. I would be grateful if you could help me.

This is the SQL that I wrote:

```
 SELECT [Tag_id]
 FROM [BitirME].[dbo].[User_Tag]
 WHERE USER_ID = '1'  AND Tag_id IN (
 SELECT [Tag_id]
 FROM [BitirME].[dbo].[User_Tag]
 where USER_ID = '3')
```

Comment: Should your example call return 100, 101, and 102?

Comment: No, just 100 and 101 because userid=1 and userid=2 has only 100 and 101 in common

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is the "Intersection" of those two sets:

```
var commonTags = database.Usr_Tags.Where(u => u.User_id == userID1).Select(u => u.Tag_id)
    .Intersect(database.Usr_Tags.Where(u => u.User_id == userID2).Select(u => u.Tag_id));
```

And voila, you're done.

Or, to clean it up a bit:

```
public static IQueryable<int> GetUserTags(int userId)
{
    return database.Usr_Tags
        .Where(u => u.User_id == userId)
        .Select(u => u.Tag_id);
}

var commonTags = GetUserTags(userID1).Intersect(GetUserTags(userID2));
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to do it:

```
int[] users = new int[] {1,3};  // for testing

database.Ustr_Tags.Where(t => users.Contains(t.User_id))
                  .GroupBy(t => t.Tag_id)
                  .Where(g => users.All(u => g.Any(gg=>gg.User_id == u)))  // all tags where all required users are tagged
                  .Select(g => g.Key);
```

One benefit of this one is it can be used for any number of users (not just 2).

Answer (score 0):

If i got it right, query like this is maybe what you need

```
var q = from t in database.Usr_Tags
        //all Usr_Tags for UserID1
        where t.User_Id == userID1 &&
        //and there is a User_tag for User_ID2 with same Tag_ID
        database.User_Tags.Any(t2=>t2.User_ID==userID2 && t2.Tag_ID==t.Tag_ID)
        select t.Tag_Id;

var commonTags = q.ToList();
```

Comment: You really want to do an inner join from Usr_Tags onto Usr_Tags, instead of performing n subselects.